# How do I download images with Parse Cloud Code and save them in an array?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, cloud

I'm using Parse.com as my backend service for an iOS app and I have one column that stores profile pictures from Facebook as URLs in an array.

Like so:

```
[
    "https://z-1-scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hp...e=5737C2D1",
    "http://files.parsetfss.com/9b0a70...40906b-newProfilePic.png",
    "http://files.parsetfss.com/9b0a70...24dd6-newProfilePic.png"
]
```

Some times theses URLs expires (due to Facebook rules) and does not contain an image. Other sides of the internet is also not recommending to store profile pictures like this.

So what I want to do is to make a Parse Cloud Code Javascript that migrates the profile picture URLs into real image files by downloading the images from the URLs and save them as Parse files in a new array in a new column.

Here is what I want to do:

- Query all users in Parse
- Get their profile picture URLs
- Download the image from every URL
- Create a image file
- Add the image to a new array
- Save that array to the user

I hope this makes sense. I have created a Cloud Code function that look like this:

Parse.Cloud.define("migrateColumn", function(request, response) {

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

var usersToSave = [];
var profileImages = [];

var userQuery = new Parse.Query("User");
userQuery.find().then(function(users) {

    for (var a = 0; a < users.length; a++) {
          var user = users[a];
          var profileURLs = user.get("profilePictures");

          for (var b = 0; b < profileURLs.length; b++) {
              var url = profileURLs[b];

              Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                    url: url
              }).then(function(httpResponse) {
                  var imageBuffer = httpResponse.buffer;
                  var base64 = imageBuffer.toString("base64");
                  var file = new Parse.File("userProfileImage.png", { base64: base64 });

                  profileImages.push(file);
              });
          }

      user.set("profileImages", ["profileImage" + (a + 1)]);
      usersToSave.push(user);
    }
}).then(function() {
    Parse.Object.saveAll(usersToSave, {
        success: function() {
            response.success("Success : " + profileImages);

        }, error: function(error) {
            response.error("An error occurred : " + error.message);
        }
    });
});
```

});

I understand that the `httpRequest` is done asynchronously and that I need to implement a `Promise` in some way, to wait for all the images to finish downloading. I don't have enough knowledge of Javascript to construct this on my own. All the help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track.  Everything will get simpler if you make functions that do logical tasks and return promises.  For example, how about a function that takes a single url and returns a single PFFile...

```
function fileFromUrl(url, name) {
    return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({url: url}).then(function(httpResponse) {
        var imageBuffer = httpResponse.buffer;
        var base64 = imageBuffer.toString("base64");
        var file = new Parse.File(name, { base64: base64 });
        // edit - pretty sure file.save resolves to file, but just in case...
        return file.save().then(function() { return file; });
    }, function(error) {
        // can't fetch the image for some reason
        // ideas:
        return null; // and have your UI check for nulls in the user image array
        // or return cannedImage(); where this function returns a promise 
        // for a PFFile that already exists
    });
}
```

Now it's easier to write one that does that for an array of urls...

```
var _ = require('underscore');
function function filesFromUrls(urls) {
    var promises = _.map(urls, function (url, index) {
        return fileFromUrl(url, ''+index);
    });
    return Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function() {
        return _.toArray(arguments);
    });
}
```

Now it's easier to do this for a user...

```
function convertUrlsToFilesForUser(user) {
    var profileURLs = user.get("profilePictures");
    return filesFromUrls(profileURLs).then(function(files) {
        // profileImages should be an array of PFFiles, not an array of arrays as you have it
        user.set("profileImages");
        return user.save();
    });
}
```

Now it's easy to do this in a cloud function...

```
var userQuery = new Parse.Query("User");
userQuery.find().then(function(users) {
    var promises = _.map(users, function(user) {
        return convertUrlsToFilesForUser(user);
    });
    return return Parse.Promise.when(promises);
}).then(function(result) {
    response.success(result);
}, function(error) {
    response.error(error);
});
```

**Caveats**:  I didn't test this code.  All that's done here is restructure of the operations to simplify and properly use promises.  Within those operations, I used your code, and I didn't test that, either.

The one design element I changed is that you appeared to saving an array of arrays `profileImages`, like: `[ [ PFFile, '0'], [ PFFile, '1'], ...`
I changed that to just an array of PFFiles.  I think you want that second element to be like a file name.  I added the name where it belongs, in the constructor to PFFile (the name of the file is unimportant, since it only affects the file's semi-opaque url which parse makes unique anyway).

**One last caveat**.  Fetching lots of users, then lots of images, then lots of saving could easily time out.  You'll probably need to run this in small batches of users to avoid time outs.

Comment: Thanks danh, this ended up working. But one concern I have is; if the URL is broken (expired) then the `httpResponse` will return as a `text/plain`. Which means that the file can't be created and thus can't be saved. So, is there a way to check in the response for `httpResponse.status == 403`?

Comment: @ViktorGidlöf, The only place in this logic where errors are caught is at the root.  If an image fetch results in an error, all the promises fall through to that `response.error()`, so only the users processed up to that point will be completed.  But promises make it easy to handle errors in context.  I've made an edit function to show how to handle a failed http request and keep going.

Comment: Yes, this is good. And I am thinking along the lines of creating a function as you mentioned called `cannedImage()` and that function would be a new `httpRequest` where I'd fetch an image from a URL that I know has an image? For instance an image that I've uploaded to my own server that contains a placeholder image. Would I do this in the error function or how do I go about creating the placeholder? Thanks!

Comment: There are several options, but I prefer leaving it null.  In most cases substituting a canned image is the business of the UI, which should use a separate architecture, optimized for static content, to get stuff like that.  If there's a good reason to do it in the cloud, then fetch the file and build the PFFile once keeping its handle in a new class.  It would be very wasteful to re-fetch and create a new PFFile each time you need the image.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out and it worked by returning a `placeholderFile()` function in the error-handle that in turn returned a placeholder image from a URL that was not broken. Now one other concern I have is that I want to make a thumbnail image from the downloaded file and set that to another column. But maybe that's another question?